# In C++ is it possible to take input with an inhibitor charachter?

Tags: c++, input

I have a c++ task that wants to me work with an input that consists of n numbered sentences and these sentences can be separated by space or a new line. So the task indicates that the input will end with the occurrence of character @. In c++ how can I take one input with n numbered sentences until @ ?

Comment: How do you differ between multiple words separated by space, and multiple sentences separated by space? When you say "sentence", do you really mean "word"?

Comment: `std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line, '@');`

Comment: @someprogrammerdude words with a space, sentences with a dot.

Comment: If the sentences are ended with a dot, then they are really *dot* separated.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to clarify. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre] of *your own* attempt and show it together with a description of the problem you have with it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are maybe right about my dealing with the forum but as Eljay immediately understood and answered, it is not a very complex question and as a written n numbered sentence with skipping the inputs including only matter a concern was the ending with @ as other can understand well.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not specif anough to give an answer.

But reading until a character appearscan be done with a simple loop. Even if you enter more data after the @, it will be ignored.

The we have the complete input in one string and split along the '.'

Maybe the following can give you at least an idea . . .

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

const std::regex re{R"(\.)"};

int main() {

    // Here we store the complete input up to a @
    std::string data{};

    char c{};
    // Read until @ found
    while (std::cin.get(c) and c != '@')
        data += c;

    // Split input into sentences.
    std::vector sentence(std::sregex_token_iterator(data.begin(), data.end(), re, -1), {});

    // Show all sentences
    for (const std::string& s : sentence) std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```